# No sound from Web Audio in chrome (currentTime always 0)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, audio, web-audio-api

My tablet is running Chrome 52.0.2743.98 but will not output sound when I go to [this Web Audio example page](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/TouchPad/index.html).

When I inspect the audio context in the console, I can see that the `currentTime` is always 0.

Pasting the following code [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode) also produces no sound:

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 'square';
oscillator.frequency.value = 3000; // value in hertz
oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
oscillator.start();
```

These two examples work well on my laptop with Chrome 52.0.2743.116.

How can I get Chrome to output sound from the Web Audio API?

Comment: This should work. The example page works for me on my phone running the same version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome Android, my recollection is that audio will only start if attached to a user interaction (e.g. a touch or click event). See also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178297

Comment: WebAudio isn't currently restricted in this way, and the example page and code snippet just use WebAudio.  Something else is going on, but I don't know what.